# "sql.run is not a function" TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I have the following code for a Discord bot I am making in Discord.JS

```
if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix+'bank')){
    var i = 0
    var total = 0
    sql.run("SELECT SUM(money) FROM money");
    msg.channel.send('** :earth_americas: | The current *GLOBAL* bank is worth e$'+total+'.**')
}
```

I get the error:

```
sql.run("SELECT SUM(money) FROM money");
       ^

TypeError: sql.run is not a function
    at Client.client.on.msg (/Users/jack/Documents/Code/EcoBot/bot.js:105:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Client.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (/Users/jack/Documents/Code/EcoBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/handlers/MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (/Users/jack/Documents/Code/EcoBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/packets/WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (/Users/jack/Documents/Code/EcoBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (/Users/jack/Documents/Code/EcoBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users/jack/Documents/Code/EcoBot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

Here is where `sql` is defined:

```
const SQLite = require("better-sqlite3");
const sql = new SQLite('./money.sqlite');
```

I have tried to find the answer, and I've been through the docs, but I have gotten nowhere. Docs are [here](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/wiki/API). Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: `console.log(SQLite)`: does it exist as expected?
`console.log(sql);`: does it exist as expected?
Sounds like an initialization problem

Comment: Are you sure you got the right docs? You import "better-sqlite3", which has the docs [here](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/wiki/API)

Comment: @ASDFGerte edited

Comment: Yes, but then it's quite obvious, there is no `.run`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Check the latest answer by RedJandal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the better-sqlite3 documentation it uses the following syntax.

```
var qry = db.prepare("SELECT SUM(money) AS total FROM money").get()
total = qry.total
```

Have a read of the documentation [here](https://github.com/JoshuaWise/better-sqlite3/wiki/API)

Comment: That worked, but however, now all I get on Discord for a response is " :earth_americas: | The current GLOBAL bank is worth e$0.", when my balance for my user is 100.

Comment: @CoderByDay I have updated the answer to set the total variable to that from the query. I really recommend you read the documentation.

Comment: I'll do that @RedJandal.

Comment: @jackmerrill Could you give him an upvote, too, if you haven't already.